# error about UTF_8 format while creating my xml using libxml and c++

Tags: c++, xml, dom, libxml2

I created an xml file using libxml and c++. What I want to do now, is reading from a .txt and put this text between some specific tags.

I have tried the following code, just reading from a file and write it between tags:

```
char * s ;
double d;

fichier>>i>>s>>d;

// fichier.close();                                                                                                                

cout << s << endl ;

 xmlNewChild(root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST "metadata",
             BAD_CAST   s );
```

While running this code, I get this error:

```
output error : string is not in UTF-8
```

So I guess that there is a format incompatibility between the input and output. Can you help me please? I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Is your source file UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your input string into UTF-8 input using one of the functions defined in the encoding module. (Or using any other encoding library you like like icu ) you can find details about the encoding module here http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-encoding.html

My guess is that you want to preserve the bytes so that what you need is something like (VERY untested and derived purely from the docs.)

```
//Get the encoding
xmlCharEncodingHandlerPtr encoder = xmlGetCharEncodingHandler(XML_CHAR_ENCODING_ASCII);

// Each ascii byte should take up at most 2 utf-8 bytes IIRC so allocate enough space.
char* buffer_utf8 = new char[length_of_s*2];

//Do the encoding
int consumed = length_of_s;
int encoded_length=length_of_s*2;

int len = (*encoder.input)(buffer_utf8, &encoded,s,&consumed);
if( len<0 ) { .. error .. }
buffer_utf8[len]=0; // I'm not sure if this is automatically appended or not.

//Now you can use buffer_utf8 rather than s.
```

If your input is in a different encoding supported by libxml then it should just be a matter of changing `XML_CHAR_ENCODING_ASCII` to the right constant, though you may need to change thenumber of bytes allocated in the in `buffer_utf8` too.